# Displaying HTML instead of preformatted text Guzzle

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, guzzle

I'm making this API call where I GET Google Books from their API. However, the end result in the browser is preformatted code in a `<pre>` tag (which ruins JSON too, and throws an error because of that tag). How can I get it so I display actual website in the browser, instead of raw code?

```
public function findAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['csrf_protection' => false])
        ->add('Volume', TextType::class)
        ->add('Search', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->submit($request->query->all());

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $client = new Client();
        $body = $client->get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=".$form->get('Volume')->getData());
        $response = $body->getBody()->getContents();
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        if(array_key_exists('items', $response)){
            return $this->render('BlogsiteSearchBundle:Page:result.html.twig', ['items' => $response['items']]);
        } else {
            return new Response('Google did not have any items for this entered data', 400);
        }
    }

    return new Response('Google Volume Not Found', 404);
}
```

Comment: You didn't provide any context, what does `$response` contain? Maybe `strip_tags()` will help?

Comment: I have a simple HTML form with GET action, which initiates an action in a controller. In this action, I create the form, see if it exists and is valid, and then run the above code. It's Symfony/Guzzle. `strip_tags()` didn't work.

Comment: If I enter `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=1` it returns a proper JSON response without and `<pre>` tags. Are you sure you are getting the right response?

Comment: Well, I am getting the full HTML code as processed through Twig, but its raw. Maybe it has something to do with this if statement? I've updated the post.

Comment: @AlvinBunk http://imgur.com/a/1NP8h

Comment: Question: Do you have code to perform the OAuth 2.0 authentication? I see [from the docs](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) you need to do that first. I tried a test myself and got the same results as you, and I know my code should work - so i'm guessing it's an authorization issue.

Comment: How do you carry out your test? I have added an API key but this does not solve the issue. Do you have a basic example or pointers towards which bundle if there is any to use for OAuth 2.0?